# What is Variable subject alternative in RxSwift 5.1?

Tags: swift, variables, reactive-programming, reactive

I need to use something like RxSwift 3.0 Variable, but in RxSwift 5.0, it's completely deprecated.

What is Variable subject alternative in Rxswift 5.1?

let overwatch = Game(price: Variable(value: 59.99))

overwatch.price.value = 12